# Reduce length of a sample matrix keeping the same proportions

Tags: matlab

I have a vector of values `Phi_Values` and a matrix `Phi_occurences` which contains the number of occurrences for each value of `Phi_Values`, and for each depht (each line represents a depth)

As an exemple (*not the real sizes & values, really too big to paste here*)

```
Phi_values =

0.2000    0.3000    0.4000    0.5000    0.6000
```

and

```
Phi_occurences =

    2000        3000          20        1980        3000
    1000        2000        3000        4000           0
    4000           0        1000        3000        2000
```

So in this example, for the depth 1, there are 2000 occurrences of 0.2, 3000 occurrences of 0.3, 20 occurrences of 0.4, ...

For every depth there are 10000 cumulative occurrences. **For some reasons, I need to get 400 cumulative occurrences but keeping the same proportions**  (*as an exemple, if i have 20% of the occurrences are for Phi_values(1), I want to keep those 20% after transformation*).

What I did is to divide `Phi_Occurrences` by 25 (10 000/25 = 400), and then to apply `round`.

```
Phi_occurences = round(Phi_occurences/25)
```

But then the cumulative occurences for each depth is not 400 anymore, but *more or less* 400 due to the round, when I need exactly 400..

I guessed for a while and I can't figure out how to get the precise number of occurrences while keeping the proportions as close as possible from the original ones

**TL;DR** : I need to divide a matrix  of positive integers (which have a sum on lines of 10 000) by 25, put the result in integer, so I get a sum of lines of exactly 400 and the line proportions as close as possible from the original matrix.

**EDIT** : As an example, if

```
Phi_occurences(1) =

2506        2507        2506        2481
```

then

```
Phi_occurences(1)/25 = 

100.2400  100.2800  100.2400   99.2400

sum(Phi_occurences(1)/25) =

400

sum(round(Phi_occurences(1)/25)) =

399
```

Comment: Please give an example where the sum is not 400.

Comment: Yup, added it on my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in those cases you could check for the highest remainder and add 1 to that number to make it 400. Your example,

```
clc
clear

a =  [2506 2507 2506 2481];

a = a./25;

b = round(a);

if sum(b) ~= 400
   [~, m] = max(rem(a, b));

   b(m) = b(m) + 1;
end

sum(b)

fprintf('\t\ta\tb\n');
disp([a' b']);
```

which gives,

```
ans =

   400

        a   b
  100.2400  100.0000
  100.2800  101.0000
  100.2400  100.0000
   99.2400   99.0000
```